# Excluding files from Project Template C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I'm creating a project template to make the development process here in the company smoother.

I've created the template and it works ok, I can create a new project based on the template. 
The only issue is that some files are included in the new project that I don't want included for instance the .vstemplate file.

I've searched the web/here on how to do this, but I can't find the answer...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Would excluding files from the template project achieve what you want? You can do that by right clicking on a file in the solution explorer and clicking `Exclude From Project`

Example:

[image: Exclude From Project]